# When should one use json body in a POST request in REST service?

Tags: javascript, json, rest

When should one use JSON body in a POST in REST service?

How many parameters / arguments would one start considering json body?

I have a case here where I would like to POST a request to a server with a list of subscription toggled explicityly.

The following is what I came up with a POST request body. But should I also consider using url arguments for factory_id?

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "is_subscribed": false,
      "game_id": 0
    },
    {
      "game_id": 1,
      "is_subscribed": true
    }
  ],
  "factory_id": 3
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think there is no clear cut answer to this - it'd depend on what you're working with and how you choose to do stuff. Or, "opinion based" in other words. You might have limitations on the choices made from what sort of things you're using, too. I'd try to answer your questions from my perspective in order - when to use JSON/how many parameters to use JSON (both have the same answer): if you have more than one value (e.g., name) then use JSON. It's just simpler. As for factory_id - depends on your URL structure but if you have anything like `/factories/3` then yes.

Comment: @user805981, did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the agreement between server and client side on the protocol used to exchange data, it can be JSON, XML and others. I don't think it's a good idea to exchange data using `URL`, since you can't transfer binary data in this way and it introduces overhead to server for parsing and assembling the message.